# C: programming: How to create main.o from main.c?

Tags: c, unix

I'm trying to write a makefile and I compiled main.c. Then I'm trying to create main.o, but I'm confused as how to do so. I'm using a vi editor in UNIX. I tried `gcc -o main.c`, I get a fatal error saying that there's no input files. What went wrong?

Comment: Well, then *there are no input files*. See the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc) for the correct invocation syntax.

Answer (score 5):

You can use gcc's `-c` option to compile a source file without linking.  This will leave you with a `.o` file:

```
gcc -c main.c
```

You can then create an executable by linking that `.o` file with the standard libraries, and other `.o` or `.c` files if you like:

```
gcc -o myprogram main.o
```

The primary advantage of this is when you have multiple `.c` files.  In that case you can save time by not recompiling them all when one of them changes.

Comment: Thank you! By the way, when I press tab, it displays a list of files in my directory instead of actually tabbing. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @Johnny Why do you want to enter an actual tab on the command line‽

Comment: @Johnny, I'd suggest you take advantage of tab completion rather than trying to get around it.  But if it's that important to you, it may work to type control-v before pressing tab.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Makefile, then you probably have too much in it.  Warning: the following will overwrite your Makefile.  Try:

```
echo 'all: main.o' > Makefile
make
```

or even:

```
> Makefile  # truncate the Makefile.  That is, make it empty
make main.o
```

or even:

```
rm Makefile
make main.o
```

Stop working so hard.